# How to override the categories view page in cs cart?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I have a new addon named `drill_search` and I need to display a message on the category view page's `view.tpl` How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override hook categories:block by adding the file bellow and filled with any code needed

```
design/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/addons/drill_search/hooks/categories/view.override.tpl
```